# PostGIS - spatial index not used on ST_Intersects when doing update

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to update the sites table with any ancient woodlands that each site intersects. I'm running the SQL that looks like below, which works but is very slow and doesn't appear to use spatial indexes. Is there a way to rewrite it that would use them?

```
UPDATE sites 
SET woodlands = (
    SELECT name 
    FROM ancientwoodlands, sites 
    WHERE ST_Intersects(
        (SELECT sites.geom WHERE sites.key_column = 1),
        ancientwoodlands.geom
    )
    LIMIT 1
) 
WHERE key_column = 1;
```

Comment: That's not even valid, what do you expect this to do? `(select sites.geom where sites.key_column={0})` I think you need a consultant.

Comment: I've edited out the python script to just show the sql

Comment: the subquery in the st_intersects seems redundant

Comment: When you unroll the query to look at it, it just doesn't look right -- the missing `FROM` stands right out.. Best practice is to use an explicit `JOIN` which can add legibility and order to SQL. `LIMIT 1` is often a hack for queries returning more rows than intended; it makes the query return one row, but it's seldom the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vince is right, a `JOIN` is usually clearer and `LIMIT 1` is just random. In your case I guess the field `woodlands` should contain the names of all woodlands intersecting. So you may want to use an [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). In case there are multiple Geometries per woodland, I added [`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

```
UPDATE sites 
SET woodlands = (
    SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT a.name,',')
    FROM ancientwoodlands a
    JOIN sites s
    ON ST_Intersects(s.geom, a.geom)
    WHERE s.key_column = 1
) 
WHERE key_column = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is great info on indexing in POSTGIS [here](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/indexing.html).  To use the index you can use && prior to ST_Intersects to first get the features that have intersecting bounding boxes.

However, this is unnecessary because the index is automatically used for ST_Intersects.

> Most of the commonly used functions in PostGIS (ST_Contains, ST_Intersects, ST_DWithin, etc) include an index filter automatically. But some functions (e.g., ST_Relate) do not include and index filter.